# Backend in Nuxt + Electron app

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex, nuxt.js

I use nuxe in electron application...
I use VUEX and I need to make a copy of the local data on the server (well, download them from the server on request). Which approach to use for requests to the server application of the ELECTRON? I so understand it is necessary to think over well system of authorization and so on?